# How to increase maxUrlLength in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Lets say I want to check if field with very long key exists in my database. So I query it like:

```
var fieldId = "Fields/Very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_LONG_FIELD_ID";

_fieldRepository.Get(fieldId);
```

And then I get **BadRequest** exception from RavenDB which says:

```
The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
```

I am using RavenDb 2330 version.

**Question:** how can I increase the maxUrlLength property in RavenDb?

Comment: did you try to change UrlSegmentMaxLength in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Use Lazy operations - this will send it as a POST and avoid this error.

Comment: what do you mean lazy operations? as I understood it's not Raven exception it's IIS exception?